# How to do multicollinearity check in logistic regression?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to do a **multicollinearity** check for **Bag of Words** for **logistic regression.** I have to add a **noise** to the matrix i.e; from **N(0,0.1)** (to add noise). I want to check the weights prior to adding the noise and also after adding the noise. If the weights differ a lot then I will know that there is a multicollinearity. I converted the text into a matrix

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer() #in scikit-learn
 final_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data['CleanedText'].values)
standardized_data = StandardScaler(with_mean=False).fit_transform(final_counts)
```

The shape of the standardized_data(sparse matrix) is as follows

```
  (0, 232)  5.28663039106
  (0, 1026) 2.09754160944
  (0, 4351) 47.1484208356
  (0, 4894) 3.62576585703
  (0, 6326) 17.496202036
  (0, 7585) 12.2994564729
  (0, 9033) 55.0542695865
  (0, 9480) 5.60252663694
  (0, 9489) 34.3093270041
```

Could anyone tell me how to add a noise to the matrix and get the weights?

Comment: Why don't you use Pearson correlation between the vector to see if they are correlated or not ?

Comment: Sure. I will do that.